# Best way to handle concurrent creation of entities in many to one relation in DB using Hibernate

Tags: java, database, hibernate, concurrency

Suppose we have entities A and B. Let the relationship between A and B is many to 1. We read messages from a queue and try to create A and B in the database. Each message contain information about A and B. If we have:

1. message for A1 and B1
2. message for A2 and B1

we want to create A1 and A2 in TableA, B1 in TableB and have foreign keys in TableA pointing to B1 i.e.
A1->B1
A2->B1

The messages are consumed concurrently i.e. thread1 handles creation of A1 and B1, while thread2 handles creation of A2. Lets assume that we have criteria to identify if B1 exists or not in TableB.

Thread1 and Thread2 will simultaneously discover that B1 is missing. They will both try to create B1. But only one of the threads must succeed. The second thread must either fail or wait.

What in your opinion is the best and most efficient way to handle such a problem? How can one of the threads discover as quickly as possible that B1 is created and fail or wait for the creation of B1?

We use Hibernate for persistence in client server application.

Comment: Would it be ok if the thread creating A2 would also create B1 and the other thread just links A1 and B1?  If so I'd probably try to create B1 and make Hibernate flush the statements (i.e. actually execute them) either directly or at least at the end of the transaction. Then catch the "duplicate entry" exception (you need a reasonable unique constraint for that) and and retry in another transaction. Whether or not you create A2 in the same transaction or not depends on your requirements and circumstances.

Comment: Thread2 creating A2 may also try to create B1. Then if tread2 transaction is executed after thread1 transaction, it will fail due to the unique constraint. But if thread2 has a lot of heavy computations to do, it would be great if somehow thread2 fails as early as possible. It is the "as early as possible " part which I find difficult to do, maybe because I am new to Hibernate. I want to learn from the collective wisdom of  Stack Overflow users. May be they know something clever that I am not aware of.

Comment: Well, you could try to do create B and A in separate transactions (or shorter: tx ). In the first tx you could try to get a reference to B and if that fails you try to create it. Should that fail with a duplicate exception another thread probably was faster so try to get a reference to B again. If you got the reference you end that first tx and start a new one for your heavy computation and to create A - you could set the B reference you got earlier in the A instance (or use the B instance's ID) to make the connection.